# Django CSRF Verification Failed when using WSGIDaemonProcess with multiple processes

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

My Django version is 2.2 and I've configured httpd.conf (Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.1 mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.7) to start a process pool like so:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my_app processes=6 threads=12 display-name=%{GROUP} home=/tmp maximum-requests=1000 inactivity-timeout=1800 request-timeout=500 python-path=${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

With this setup, I would get `Forbidden 403 errors` with `CSRF verification failed` message when I do a POST request.

If I keep refreshing the page, when I get lucky, my POST request would succeed. Now I'm guessing this is because the request might have landed onto the wsgi process with the Django instance that has the "right cache".

To test the above theory, if I change the httpd.conf to have only 1 pool process like below, I do not get the 403 error.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my_app processes=1 threads=12 display-name=%{GROUP} home=/tmp maximum-requests=1000 inactivity-timeout=1800 request-timeout=500 python-path=${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

I have followed the CSRF specific instructions on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) and tried both scenarios when `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` is set to `True` or `False`

What is the recommended approach to configuring Django if I intend to spin up a pool for wsgi processes each of which would run my Django app?

I did some testing and confirmed that my views.py does not get called when the 403 error happens. So Django is rejecting the POST request before it even attempts to call views.py. Below is a snippet of the views.py:

```
def my_func(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        # some logic

        try:
            response = ... # some logic to build response
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('\n'.join(errors))

    return render(request, 'my_app/my_template.html', locals())
```

The template in use has a simple form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
```

To submit the form, there is an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: ".",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        // some code
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, e) {
        // some code
    }
});
```

This is a snippet of my httpd.conf

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 50000
LimitRequestLine      50000
TimeOut 600

LoadModule access_compat_module            modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule alias_module                    modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule auth_gssapi_module              modules/mod_auth_gssapi.so
LoadModule authn_core_module               modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module               modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module               modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module               modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule filter_module                   modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule info_module                     modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule log_config_module               modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module                     modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module              modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule negotiation_module              modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule status_module                   modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule unixd_module                    modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule wsgi_module                     modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule setenvif_module                 modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule env_module                      modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module                  modules/mod_include.so

WSGISocketPrefix ${MY_SOCKET_PREFIX}
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGIScriptReloading On


WSGIDaemonProcess my_app processes=6 threads=12 display-name=%{GROUP} home=/tmp maximum-requests=1000 inactivity-timeout=1800 request-timeout=500 python-path=${HTTPD_my_app_PYTHONPATH}

#If I use the below that has processes=1 instead I do not get CSRF verification failure
#WSGIDaemonProcess my_app processes=1 threads=12 display-name=%{GROUP} home=/tmp maximum-requests=1000 inactivity-timeout=1800 request-timeout=500 python-path=${HTTPD_my_app_PYTHONPATH}

Listen ${HTTPD_my_app_PORT}
<VirtualHost *:${HTTPD_my_app_PORT}>

    Redirect / http://${MY_HOST}:${HTTPD_my_app_PORT_REDIRECT}/
</VirtualHost>

Listen ${HTTPD_my_app_PORT_REDIRECT}
<VirtualHost *:${HTTPD_my_app_PORT_REDIRECT}>
    WSGIScriptAlias / ${HTTPD_my_app_BASE_DIR}/my_app_dir/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup my_app
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    <Directory "${HTTPD_my_app_BASE_DIR}/my_app_dir/">
      <Files wsgi.py>
        AuthType GSSAPI
        AuthName "MY_ENTITY/GSSAPI"
        GssapiCredStore keytab:${MY_KEYTAB}
        GssapiAllowedMech krb5
        GssapiPublishErrors On

        SetHandler wsgi-script
        Require valid-user
      </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory ${HTTPD_my_app_BASE_DIR}/my_app_dir/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory ${HTTPD_my_app_BASE_DIR}/static_files>
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "right cache"? Django CSRF protection doesn't use caches. If you show your view and template it might show where the problem is. If you think it might be `mod_auth_gssapi` that's causing the issue, then I would add more information about how you've implemented that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added some more info. A django process somehow must know about the token to do the verification - so by "right cache" I just mean whatever knowledge that the django process knows about the token. Because there is a pool of django processes, I am just guessing that not all of the django processes have the knowledge about the token. In the end, I'm just curious about why when I set processes=1 then there is no CSRF verification issue whereas I set processes to more than one that I start seeing the issue?

Comment: Django does not keep track of the tokens. It compares the cookie with the value from the hidden form field/HTTP header. See [how it works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#how-it-works).

Comment: With the above understanding from the link you provided, why doesn't it work when processes parameter is set to more than 1 whereas it works when processes=1?

Comment: I don't know why it is working. I haven't come across `mod_auth_gssapi` before, so it might be worth seeing if you have the same issue if you don't use it. Maybe you're hitting [this issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in) where logins cause CSRF failures. You didn't show your view, but there could be an issue with how the previous view was rendered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. I added the view into the question - I use `render` for the intial GET request but then for the POST request I do a `HttpResponse` to return a JSON. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: The view looks ok. I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: I believe I just figured it out - added an answer. Do let me know what you think. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Even if you only have one worker, you shouldn't generate the secret key when the settings are loaded in production, because it will break other things as well. For example password reset links are invalid if the secret key changes.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be due to a programmatically generated random value being assigned to `SECRET_KEY` in the `settings.py` file - essentially this was being done in `settings.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = generate_a_random_string()
```

Many thanks to Alasdair, I had another closer look at the official docs on [how Django does CRSF verification](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#how-it-works) and noticed these bits specifically:

> A hidden form field with the name ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’ present in all
>   outgoing POST forms. The value of this field is, again, **the value of
>   the secret**, with a salt which is both added to it and used to scramble
>   it. The salt is regenerated on every call to get_token() so that the
>   form field value is changed in every such response.
>
> For all incoming requests that are not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   or TRACE, a CSRF cookie must be present, and the ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’
>   field must be present and correct. If it isn’t, the user will get a
>   403 error.
>
> When validating the ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’ field value, **only the
>   secret**, not the full token, is compared with the secret in the cookie
>   value. This allows the use of ever-changing tokens. While each request
>   may use its own token, **the secret remains common to all**.
>
> **This check is done by CsrfViewMiddleware**.

So my problem was that Apache was spinning up multiple wsgi Django instances/processes but each of them would have a different `SECRET_KEY`. So although Django does not really keep track of the full tokens themselves, the Django instance does need to know/have the corresponding secret key that, along with some non-edible salt, made up the tokens.

So the solution to the problem was to make the `SECRET_KEY` the same across all Django processes that Apache spins up.